# Angularjs, search form, factory: Button doesn't work

Tags: forms, button, service, angularjs, factory

I have a typical form-with-query-editor and search button im my Angularjs-app. However, clicking the search-button doesn't work. If I initially open the form with the table, the service works. But not when clicking the search button. The code is as follows:

HTML vlist.html:

```
<input ng-model="nachname" type="text" id="nachname" name="nachname" class="search-query" />
<button ng-click="search()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
...
<tr ng-repeat="pers in personen">
  <td>{{pers.nachname}}</td>
</tr>
...
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module( 'cdemoApp', [ 'cdemo.services' ] );

app.config( ['$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider ) {
    $routeProvider.
    when( '/vlist', {
        controller: 'VListCtrl',
        resolve: {
            personlistdto: function( VListLoader ) {
                return VListLoader();
            }
        },
        templateUrl : 'app/view/vlist.html'
             } ).otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' } );
} ] );

app.controller( 'VListCtrl', [ '$scope', 'personlistdto',
                                          function( $scope, personlistdto  ) {
     $scope.search = function(){
            $scope.personen = personlistdto.aaData;
            $scope.iTotalRecords = personlistdto.iTotalRecords;
      };
     $scope.search();
}]);
```

Service:

```
var services = angular.module( 'cdemo.services', [ 'ngResource' ] );

services.factory( 'Vers', [ '$resource',
                            function find( $resource ) {
    return $resource( '/cdemo/rest/vers/ajs/:id',
            { id: '@id', isArray: false }
    );
} ] );


services.factory( 'VListLoader', [ 'Vers', '$q',
                                       function( Vers, $q ) {
    console.log('Vloader1');
    var find = function find() {
        var delay = $q.defer();
        Vers.get( function( personlistdto ) {
            delay.resolve( personlistdto );
        }, function() {
            delay.reject( 'Nix fetch' );
        } );
        return delay.promise;
    };

    return find;
} ] );
```

Any idea how I can get the button searching (including fields/parameters) - because nothing happens when clicking the button? Thanks for an answer.

Comment: Are the `<input>` and `<button>` elements inside a `<form>`?  If so, what/where is the submit handler?  Otherwise, there is no click-handler or `ng-click` tied to the button.  Unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: The click-handler should be in the VListCtrl and invoke VListLoader with search fields - but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm just guessing that you want a search field for names in your list.  If so, the button is not required, and you can easily filter through your content. [Here's a plunk](http://plunker.co/edit/ObiTzrBxa58gCEfOLpHr?p=preview) that demonstrates the basic filter.  This doesn't answer "button doesn't work", but it might give the desired outcome.

Comment: I added the click-handler search in the code above. But nothing happens - the function is called (I can see it with console.log), but the service isn't called again when clicking the button. And the parameter seems not be set (in $scope.name it is ok).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by changing the controller like this:

```
  app.controller( 'VListCtrl', [ '$scope', 'personlistdto', 'VListLoader', 
                                              function( $scope, personlistdto, VListLoader  ) {
        $scope.personlistdto = personlistdto;
        $scope.searchFactory = VListLoader;
        $scope.search =  function( ){
            $scope.personlistdto = $scope.searchFactory();
        };

    }
    ]  );
```

This way the Factory VListLoader is called.